# How can I create a script that will lock specific cells base on dropdown?

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]

- If I select training report, I want to input data on the orange color and the other color is locked.
- If I select meeting report,  I want to input data on the orange color and the other color is locked.
- If I select coaching report, I want to input data on the orange color and the other color is locked.

Comment: Take a look at protected ranges. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection.  If you get stuck with a particular piece of code post it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try, `Class Protection`

> Access and modify protected ranges and sheets. A protected range can protect either a static range of cells or a named range.

```
// Protect range A1:B10, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var range = ss.getRange('A1:B10');
 var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');

 // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
 // permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
 var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 protection.addEditor(me);
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
   protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
```

For more information here is the [Tutorial](https://developers.googleblog.com/2015/02/control-protected-ranges-and-sheets-in.html) and documentation about [Protection Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#methods).